# C unknown type name stack

Tags: c, types, compiler-errors, linked-list, header-files

I wanted to implement a stack as a linked list, but every time I try to compile `main` it says that error is in `"main.h" at "stack* head"`...

> ```
> error: unknown type name ‘stack’
>       unsigned long int inst_len, cell *d_tape, unsigned int dt_index, stack *head);
> ```

**This is my "main.h" header file:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stack.h"

#define SUCCESS 0
#define FAIL -1
#define CELLMAX 255
#define CELLMIN 0
#define ARRJMP 10
#define DTMAXLEN 30000

typedef unsigned char cell;

int loop(cell *ins_tape, unsigned long int *inst_index,
         unsigned long int inst_len, cell *d_tape,
         unsigned int dt_index, stack *head);
```

It says that the error is in the last parameter to function loop "`stack *head`"

**This is file "stack.h":**

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include "main.h"

typedef struct Stack{
    unsigned long int begin_index;
    unsigned long int end_index;
    struct Stack *prev;
} stack;

int initStack(stack *head);
int pushStack(stack *head, unsigned long int b_i, unsigned long int e_i);
int popStack(stack *head);

#endif
```

I use these functions in `loop()` function, it doesn't show me any errors in `stack.h`, but I think that's maybe because it terminated at the `loop()` declaration first.

Thanks for every help, sorry if this is already answered somewhere. I already looked at a couple of questions but they had different problems.

Comment: Circular inclusion...

Comment: Why do you include main.h in stack.h?

Comment: @giuseppe-dandrea because I have other things in main.h.. like definitions for return values and such, i think it doesnt really affect the error so i didnt copied it here.

Comment: @Angew Really? I thought that #ifndef will solve this issue, i had that error before i added that #ifndef, it kept repeating the same errors in terminal, but now it doesnt do that.

Comment: @RollAndSchullz I just compiled your code without the main.h include and it shows no error, so the problem is circular inclusion

Comment: @giuseppe-dandrea Thanks. But how should i proceed, i though that #ifndef will solve this issue, and then, what if i need to use the defined values i have in main.h (i mean, without copying them to stack.h) :/

Comment: @RollAndSchullz `#ifndef` indeed prevents circular inclusion, but the problem is that your headers depend on each other, so they'd need the (impossible) circular inclusion to work correctly. You need to reorganise them.

Answer (score 1):

The #ifndef/#endif block is disabling all of the contents from stack.h from being placed before the contents of main.h whenever a file includes stack.h.

To fully explain this issue I'm going to step through the related preprocessor steps.  There will be a summary with possible solutions below, but if you have any questions please be sure to read through this entire post.

Consider the below test file.

**test.c:**

```
#include "stack.h"

int DoFoo(void)
{
    return;
}
```

The preprocessor replace #include "stack.h" with the contents of stack.h.

**test.c expansion 1:**

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include "main.h"

typedef struct Stack{
    unsigned long int begin_index;
    unsigned long int end_index;
    struct Stack *prev;
} stack;

int initStack(stack *head);
int pushStack(stack *head, unsigned long int b_i, unsigned long int e_i);
int popStack(stack *head);

#endif

int DoFoo(void)
{
    return;
}
```

Next the preprocessor reloves the #ifndef STACK_H, which is evaluated to true, so the contents inside of the #ifndef and #endif are preserved.

**test.c expansion 2:**

```
#define STACK_H

#include "main.h"

typedef struct Stack{
    unsigned long int begin_index;
    unsigned long int end_index;
    struct Stack *prev;
} stack;

int initStack(stack *head);
int pushStack(stack *head, unsigned long int b_i, unsigned long int e_i);
int popStack(stack *head);


int DoFoo(void)
{
    return;
}
```

I'll ignore the `#define STACK_H` for now.  The next major step is replace `#include "main.h"` with the contents of main.h

**test.c expansion 3:**

```
#define STACK_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stack.h"

#define SUCCESS 0
#define FAIL -1
#define CELLMAX 255
#define CELLMIN 0
#define ARRJMP 10
#define DTMAXLEN 30000

typedef unsigned char cell;

int loop(cell *ins_tape, unsigned long int *inst_index,
         unsigned long int inst_len, cell *d_tape,
         unsigned int dt_index, stack *head);

typedef struct Stack{
    unsigned long int begin_index;
    unsigned long int end_index;
    struct Stack *prev;
} stack;

int initStack(stack *head);
int pushStack(stack *head, unsigned long int b_i, unsigned long int e_i);
int popStack(stack *head);


int DoFoo(void)
{
    return;
}
```

I'm next going to replace `#include "stack.h"` with the contents of stack.h,  just like we did earlier.

**test.c expansion 4:**

```
#define STACK_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include "main.h"

typedef struct Stack{
    unsigned long int begin_index;
    unsigned long int end_index;
    struct Stack *prev;
} stack;

int initStack(stack *head);
int pushStack(stack *head, unsigned long int b_i, unsigned long int e_i);
int popStack(stack *head);

#endif

#define SUCCESS 0
#define FAIL -1
#define CELLMAX 255
#define CELLMIN 0
#define ARRJMP 10
#define DTMAXLEN 30000

typedef unsigned char cell;

int loop(cell *ins_tape, unsigned long int *inst_index,
         unsigned long int inst_len, cell *d_tape,
         unsigned int dt_index, stack *head);

typedef struct Stack{
    unsigned long int begin_index;
    unsigned long int end_index;
    struct Stack *prev;
} stack;

int initStack(stack *head);
int pushStack(stack *head, unsigned long int b_i, unsigned long int e_i);
int popStack(stack *head);


int DoFoo(void)
{
    return;
}
```

Note that there is a `#define STACK_H` before the `#ifndef STACK_H`, so we can remove all of the contents in the #ifndef/#endif block.

**test.c expansion 5:**

```
#define STACK_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SUCCESS 0
#define FAIL -1
#define CELLMAX 255
#define CELLMIN 0
#define ARRJMP 10
#define DTMAXLEN 30000

typedef unsigned char cell;

int loop(cell *ins_tape, unsigned long int *inst_index,
         unsigned long int inst_len, cell *d_tape,
         unsigned int dt_index, stack *head);

typedef struct Stack{
    unsigned long int begin_index;
    unsigned long int end_index;
    struct Stack *prev;
} stack;

int initStack(stack *head);
int pushStack(stack *head, unsigned long int b_i, unsigned long int e_i);
int popStack(stack *head);


int DoFoo(void)
{
    return;
}
```

**Summary:**

In the above file the problem should be fairly clear.  The declaration for loop() uses the type stack before it is defined.

**Solutions:**

1) Always include main.h before including stack.h  (this is a very poor solution)

2) It doesn't realy make sense for there to be two header files that when you inculde either of them both are always included as a result.  Consider merging these header files.

3) Split the contents needed in both header files into its own header file.  Both main.h and stack.h will then include this new header file and not each other.

4) Move all of the contents that stack.h needs into stack.h and delete `#include "main.h"` from stack.h.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the attempted circular inclusion: `main.h` includes `stack.h`, which includes `main.h`. `main.h` doesn't have an include guard, so it gets parsed before `stack.h` and thus the declarations from `stack.h` are not yet visible.

In your particular case, nothing from `main.h` is needed in `stack.h`, so you can easily just remove the `#include "main.h"` line from `stack.h` and it will work.

In the general case, such (attempted) circular inclusions must be prevented by restructuring headers so that their dependencies contain no cycles (i.e. form a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)). This can be done by judicious usage of forward declarations.  In your case, that could mean forward-declaring `struct Stack` and the typedef in `main.h`, so that it won't need to include `stack.h` either:

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SUCCESS 0
#define FAIL -1
#define CELLMAX 255
#define CELLMIN 0
#define ARRJMP 10
#define DTMAXLEN 30000


typedef struct Stack stack;

typedef unsigned char cell;

int loop(cell *ins_tape, unsigned long int *inst_index,
         unsigned long int inst_len, cell *d_tape,
         unsigned int dt_index, stack *head);

#endif
```